# Flavor specific views not compiling under other build variants

Tags: java, android, android-flavors

I have one `MainActivity.java` activity, one `main.xml` file and multiple flavors, each flavor having its own version of `main.xml` which gets priority over the main flavor's `main.xml` file, and each flavor has its unique views.

The problem is that when choosing some build variant (some flavor) the other flavors' unique views don't compile ('cannot find symbol') on their `findViewById(R.id.someflavorUniqueViewId)` because clearly they are not existing in this flavor.

The solution I found was to make some 'dummy views' that are empty so that all views appear in all flavors and this solves it, but it's messy and if I would have a lot of flavors, then any update of some flavor to contain a new view would require adding these 'dummy views' in all corresponding layout files, which doesn't make much sense.

Is there a better solution for this problem?

Was hoping for something like this but couldn't find a way to do it:

```
if (viewExists("someFlavorUniqueViewName")) {
    int flavorUniqueId = getViewId("someFlavorUniqueViewName");
    View flavorUniqueView = findViewById(flavorUniqueId);
}
```

Edit: I found how to solve it programmatically:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("someFlavor")) {
    int flavorUniqueId = getResources().getIdentifier("someFlavorUniqueViewName", "id", getPackageName());
    View flavorUniqueView = findViewById(flavorUniqueId);
    // do something...
}
```

I believe this has a slight efficiency drawback versus the XML solution in Ruslan's answer, but I ended up using this one since I was actually updating a huge code base and didn't want to change too much there. So in case anyone facing this problem, this is another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare all Flavor dependant IDs beforehand under `values/ids.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...
   <item type="id" name="someflavorUniqueViewId1"/>
...
</resources>
```

And in xml layout files you can assign IDs which you already declared, e.g.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@id/someflavorUniqueViewId1" ...
```

Please note that I'm using `@id` and not `@+id`. That is because ID is already declared in `ids.xml`, so we don't need to create a new one.

After that you could check your build Flavor in runtime and act accordingly.

```
@Nullable View optionalView1;

if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("flavor1")) {
    optionalView1 = findViewById(R.id.someflavorUniqueViewId1);
}
```

You just mark all Flavor dependant views as `@Nullable`, so IDE will help you not to forget to check for null in places where it is needed.

Also, please consider switching to [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), it has some advantages over finding view manually by id.

Comment: It still didn't not compile, saying cannot find symbol 'someflavorUniqueViewId'

Comment: @user20958695 right, we have to declare IDs beforehand, so they will always exist, even if you are not using them in some particular flavor. I have updated my answer.